# With nested UIScrollViews, how do I disable the parent UIScrollView when inner view is being scrolled?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

With nested UIScrollViews, how do I disable the parent UIScrollView when inner view is being scrolled?

I have a parent view that is a UIScrollView and one of it's child views in a UITableView (which inherits UIScrollView). When scrolling the inner UITableView, I don't want the other view to scroll.

The behaviour I'm seeing is when scrolling the inner view, it behaves as I want it, until it reaches the end. Once the UITableView has reached the end, the parent UIScrollView starts scrolling. How can I disable this?

If the touch is on the UITableView, the UIScrollView should never scroll.

I tried making a UIView a parent of the UITableView. I gave that view some gesture recognizers, which blocked the gestures from going up to the parent UIScrollView. Almost what I wanted, except my UITableView no longer bounces when trying to scroll past the end.

Anybody know the correct way to get the behaviour I want?

Comment: I am looking for the same answer in react native

Answer (score 1):

There are several properties, which disable user interaction or scrolling:

collectionView.isScrollEnabled or
collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled

There are also delegate method on scroll view that are being called once scrolling has been finished:

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) { }

You may just set properties according to your needs, so that scroll view won't scroll at the time table view is scrolling.

Thanks.